# Reformat collection using aggregation pipeline in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of next objects:

```js
{
   "_did": "213412323234",
   "metadata": [
      {
         "id": "Language",
         "value": "EN"
      },
      {
         "id": "City",
         "value": "New York"
      },
      {
         "id": "Gender",
         "value": "Male"
      }
   ]
}
```

After using some pipeline operators (maybe $project), I expect something like this:

```
{
  "id": "213412323234",
  "metadata": {
    "Language": "EN",
    "City": "New York",
    "Gender": "Male"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to just $project the data, or convert data in DB?

Comment: db.myCollection.aggregate({
// anything you want
})

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: what is the version of mongodb you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the position of elements in the `metadata` field and the keys of embedded documens is known and then you can use aggregation.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {
    $project : {
      data : {
        "Language" : {
          $arrayElemAt : ["$metadata", 0]
        },
        "City" : {
          $arrayElemAt : ["$metadata", 1]
        },
        "Gender" : {
          $arrayElemAt : ["$metadata", 2]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project : {
      metadata : {
        Language : "$data.Language.value",
        City : "$data.City.value",
        Gender : "$data.Gender.value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result :

```
{ "_id" : "213412323234", "metadata" : { "Language" : "EN", "City" : "New York", "Gender" : "Male" } }
```

If any of the above two preconditions mentioned above are not known, you can use [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/).

```
db.foo.mapReduce(function () {
  var key = this._id;
  var metadata = this.metadata;
  var valueEmit = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < metadata.length; i++) {
    valueEmit[metadata[i].id] = metadata[i].value;
  }
  emit(key, valueEmit)
},
function(key, values) {
  // do nothing as it won't be called 
  // for if value is only one 
  // for a key
},
{
  out : {replace : "foobar"}
})
```

Result :

```
> db.foobar.find()
{ "_id" : "213412323234", "value" : { "Language" : "EN", "City" : "New York", "Gender" : "Male" } }
```

Notice that the key has been changed to `value` instead of metadata. This can be easily fixed using a `$project` in `aggregation` on `foobar` collection.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947) feature request and its solution, the new feature will be added for this functionality - Function called `arrayToObject`.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    metadata: {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $map: {
          input: "$metadata",
          as: "pair",
          in: ["$$pair.id", "$$pair.value"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But at the moment, **no solution**. I suggest you to change your data structure. As far as I see there are many feature requests labeled as *Major* but not done for years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query script

```
var results = db.meta.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    id: "$_did",
    _id: 0,
    keys: "$metadata.id",
    values: "$metadata.value"
  }
}])

function object(keys, values) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var index in keys) {
    obj[keys[index]] = values[index];
  }
  return obj;
}

results = results.map(function (res) {
  return {
    id: res.id,
    metadata: object(res.keys, res.values)
  }
})
```