# MongoDB: Aggregation Group operation over a dynamic key-value pair

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, key-value

I have a simple document with one field as a key-value pair. I want to just perform a group operation in Aggregation over those keys and add their values. But the keys in the pair are not fixed and can be anything.

Here is a sample document.

```
{
    _id: 349587843,
    matchPair: {
        3 : 21,
        9 : 4,
        7 : 32
    }
},
{
    _id: 349587478,
    matchPair: {
        7 : 11,
        54 : 32,
        9 : 7,
        2 : 19
    }
}
```

And I want a result something like the following.

```
{
    _id : 3,
    count : 21
},
{
    _id : 9,
    count : 11
},
{
    _id : 7,
    count : 43
},
{
    _id : 54,
    count : 32
},
{
    _id : 2,
    count : 19
}
```

I have the following query in mind and tried using `$unwind`operation but it doesn't work probably because "matchPair" isn't an array and I don't know what to specify for the `$sum`operation.

```
db.MatchPairs.aggregate([
   { "$unwind" : "$matchPair" },
   { "$group" : {
       _id: "$matchPair",
       count : { $sum : $matchPair }
   } }
]);
```

I could also try Map-Reduce but for that too I need to `emit()` keys and values by name.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: this is not possible with the aggregation framework if your keys are dynamic, so you have to go for mapReduce

Comment: I see. Could you please tell me how I would specify keys and values in the `emit()` function?

Comment: An example of map reduce for similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41634637/2965883

Answer (score 2):

:
You could start by projecting and reshaping the `matchPair` field with `$objectToArray`

> New in version 3.4.4.

```
{
    $project: {
        matchPair: { $objectToArray: '$matchPair' }
    }
}
```

which would give

```
{
    matchPair: [{ k: 3, v: 21 }, { k: 9, v: 4 }, ...] 
}
```

Then `$unwind` based on `matchPair`

```
{
    $unwind: '$matchPair'
}
```

which would give

```
{
    matchPair: { k: 3, v: 21 }
}
```

Then `$project`

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: '$matchPair.k',
        count: '$matchPair.v'
    }
}
```

That should give the output you want. Altogether would be

```js
.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            matchPair: { $objectToArray: '$matchPair' }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$matchPair' },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$matchPair.k',
            count: '$matchPair.v'
       }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the mongoDb documentation for `$unwind`:

> Deconstructs an **array field** from the input documents to output a
>   document for each element.

So you have to change your schema for something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b57b039a3c89c1db145a"),
    "matchPair" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "count" : 21
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "9",
            "count" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "7",
            "count" : 32
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b58c039a3c89c1db145b"),
    "matchPair" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "7",
            "count" : 11
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "54",
            "count" : 32
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "9",
            "count" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "count" : 19
        }
    ]
}
```

Then doing:

```
db.MatchPairs.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$matchPair" }
]);
```

will return:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b57b039a3c89c1db145a"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "3",
        "count" : 21
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b57b039a3c89c1db145a"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "9",
        "count" : 4
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b57b039a3c89c1db145a"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "7",
        "count" : 32
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b58c039a3c89c1db145b"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "7",
        "count" : 11
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b58c039a3c89c1db145b"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "54",
        "count" : 32
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b58c039a3c89c1db145b"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "9",
        "count" : 7
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5880b58c039a3c89c1db145b"),
    "matchPair" : {
        "_id" : "2",
        "count" : 19
    }
}
```

Then you just have to do your grouping.